# Bash syntax error in CIS document

Tags: linux, bash, centos, find, xargs

I'm working on implementing changes as required by CIS standards for section 9.1.12 (CentOS 6.)  The following command returns a syntax error:

```
df --local -P | awk {'if (NR!=1) print $6'} | xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -group -ls
```

The error I get is:

```
find: `-ls' is not the name of an existing group
find: `-ls' is not the name of an existing group
find: `-ls' is not the name of an existing group
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this syntax?  The point is to find and print un-grouped files and directories.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-group` option expects an argument.  For example, `-group ichtys` to find files owned by the group `ichtys`.  You appear to be looking for the `-nogroup` option.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  The point of this command, according to the CIS document is to locate files that are owned by users or groups not listed in the system configuration files.  I'm looking for the correct syntax to do this.

Comment: You seem to have lost the "no" in `-nogroup`.